# How to go from individual date/time log to "timeline" graph?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have essentially a log file in a Google Sheets. Columns are "Date/time", "user", "asset accessed", and there will be multiple entries for the same date, though usually not time.

I'd like to use the timeline graph to show user activity, but the graph requires an aggregate view with one date (no time) per row, with a numeric count in second col. Is there a way using functions within Google Sheets to generate an aggregate "view" of this data and pass this to the timeline graph?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you'll have to create an auxiliary sheet, or just some columns with the summarized values for you chart.

From your description, I'll assume you're using 3 columns (ABC). Let's use columns D, E and F with the following formulas:

```
=ArrayFormula(Trunc(A:A))
=Unique(D:D)
=ArrayFormula(CountIf(D:D;E:E))
```

Since date values are actually a number (qtt of days since the epoch), and hours are decimals, the `Trunc` formula gets rid of the "time" part and leaves only the date. Just format the cells (apparently numbers) as dates and you'll see. Then Unique and CountIf do the summarizing.

There's surely different ways of doing this, perhaps more "elegantly", in a single formula. But I think that in this way it's more easy to understand and learn from. Also, you'll probably need to adapt the ranges to your actual columns positions (I hope that's not a problem).